# How to check if a string is IN a text[]?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the code I am running in postgres:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 'oz' != ANY(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[]) THEN 'HELOO' ELSE 'WOAH' END;
```

AFAIK, this should select 'WOAH' but it gives 'HELOO'. Now, with any string on the left side, it always selects 'HELOO' (I have tried 'monkey', and 'mg').

When I run the same code but now without a `!`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 'oz' = ANY(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[]) THEN 'HELOO' ELSE 'WOAH' END;
```

It works as intended i.e. it selects 'HELOO' and when the left side string is 'monkey', it selects 'WOAH'.

How can I check here if the left side string is NOT in the right side text[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation of `ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16):

> The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is "true" if any true result is obtained.

So when you say `'oz' != ANY(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[])`, Postgres examines in turn `'oz' != 'oz'`, `'oz' != 'l'`, `'oz' != 'm'`, and `'oz' != 'g'`. Although the first of those is `false`, the others are `true`, so the `ANY` expression is `true`.

What you want instead is `ALL`, where:

> The result is “false” if any false result is found.

So when you say `'oz' != ALL(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[])`, Postgres examines the same set of comparisons, but because the first one is `false`, the whole expression is `false`.

Effectively, `ANY` is using an `OR` between the possibilities, and `ALL` is using an `AND`.

This explains why `NOT ('oz' = ANY(('{oz,l}')::text[]))` also works: it is equivalent to `NOT ('oz' = 'oz' OR 'oz' = 'l')` and [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) tell us that's the same as `(NOT 'oz' = 'oz') AND (NOT 'oz' = 'l')`; that is `('oz' != 'oz') AND ('oz' != 'l')`, which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You want `<> ALL`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 'oz' <> ALL(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[])
             THEN 'HELOO' ELSE 'WOAH'
        END);
```

Note that the important part is `ALL`; `!=` also works but `<>` is the traditional SQL operator for not-equals.

I should note that you can also use:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NOT ('oz' = ANY(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[]))
             THEN 'HELOO' ELSE 'WOAH'
        END);
```

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b1b02aba046dfd6d22e91eb4e9689ae1)

You can either use the construction: `'oz' = ANY('{...}') IS NOT TRUE`

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 'oz' = ANY(('{oz,l,m,g}')::text[]) IS NOT TRUE THEN 'HELOO' 
        ELSE 'WOAH' 
    END;
```

or use a completely different quantifier function: `ALL` as @GordonLinoff said